# Installing Magento 2.0.2 on Nginx setup page not functioning

Tags: php, magento, nginx, url-rewriting, magento-2.0

Need some help installing Magento 2.0.2 on nginx 1.9.3 with php-fpm currently I'm using the default configuration provided by Magento ( https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/nginx.conf.sample ).

The issue that's happening is when accessing /setup after unpacking it I'm presented with a 403 on "setup/index.php/navigation" as well as other URLs the page attempts to access.

I've realized the issue behind this is that it's not passing "navigation" as an argument to the index.php file and is actually looking for "index.php/navigation" as a file and attempting to pass that to php5-fpm which results in security.limit_extensions to be triggered causing the 403.

So the question becomes how do I get requests to process properly?
E.X. when the javascript being rendered by the setup index.php requests index.php/navigation how do I ensure it's passed to index.php as an argument instead of trying to look for a file at "index.php/navigation" as if index.php were a directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem become more and more common as I can see. It seems that fastcgi_split_path_info needs to define. Try to changed nginx.conf.sample /setup location block (I pointed to solution-code with ##) to:

```
location /setup {
root $MAGE_ROOT;
location ~ ^/setup/index.php {

    ### This fixes the problem:
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    ################################

    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
    deny all;
}

location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}}
```

Comment: I had actually forgot I made this post but I fixed it a few days ago and figured out this was the exact issue, thanks.

Comment: you rock @PermaNull :)